# Wireless stop working after MAC change

Tags: mac

I am trying to spoof MAC with

```
ifconfig wlan down
macchanger --random wlan
ifconfig wlan up
```

MAC changes, but internet stops working. If I try to reconnect to wi-fi network, than internet begin to work, but MAC resets to it's default.

How can I fix this nonsense?

Comment: Anybody help???

Answer (score 0):

1) Save the contents of the code block into a `.sh` file.

2) Then, run `chmod +x what-you-called-it.sh`

3) Finally, you can run it with `sudo ./what-you-called-it.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

clear
printf "Stopping network service... "
service network-manager stop > /dev/null
echo "done"
sleep 1
printf "Bringing wlan0 down... "
sleep 1
ifconfig wlan0 down
echo "done"
sleep 1
printf "Changing MAC address... "
sleep 1
ifconfig wlan0 hw ether 00:11:22:33:44:55
echo "done"
sleep 1
printf "Bringing wlan0 up... "
sleep 1
ifconfig wlan0 up
echo "done"
sleep 1
printf "Starting network service... "
sleep 1
service network-manager start > /dev/null
echo "done"
echo
```